# How can I add async javascript to WordPress menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, asynchronous

I'm trying to add the following javascript code to a WordPress menu button.

```
<script async="async" src="https://static.cozycal.com/embed/v1/123.js"></script>
```

The menu item number is 2.

How can I achieve this? Would greatly apprecaite any help provided.

Comment: You don't "add" Javascript to a button. What do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you for your response.I'm trying to add script to the menu. So when clicked, it will show a pop up window generated by cozycal url.